# How to remove the blue vertical bar on the right and red dotted line at the top of the page in my word document

Tags: microsoft-word, format

It's the first time I see those bar and can't figure out a way to remove them. My search on the web lead nowhere, I can't right click on it, it's only visible in the print layout view.

See image here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking them and seeing if they are an object that can be deleted? Do they appear on a brand new document or just this one?

Comment: Hi, Adam. I tried clicking them without success. They can't be deleted. They don't appear on a brand new document but if I copy and past on a brand new document they will follow the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like they are object of some kind which are part of the document content. Try turning on formatting marks and see if it is a shape or has an anchor. Otherwise try removing parts of your document one by one until it disappears. You can then narrow down where these objects are located.

Comment: Thank you so much Adam, this is fantastic. When I turned on the formatting marks I did not see any thing special but when I was done deleting everything, only the blue line and a page break remained. Selecting and deleting the page break did the trick.

Comment: @Francis, Interesting, I'm glad you found the source of the issue :)